# How to retain global variables across modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, trace

I have a module: `generate_ruml` that has a global variable, `foo`. When I run the script `python3 generate_ruml.py`, it works.

However, when I call the function of `generate_ruml` (function name is: `gruml()`) from another module: `gruml_cli` using `python3 gruml_cli.py`, the global variable is not accessed and is considered as `None` while using [Trace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html).

How do I make the line `global foo` work?

Below is the code for `generate_ruml`:

```
foo = None

class GRUML:
    def generate_sequential_function_calls(self):
        """generate sequential function calls
        for tracing source code and plotting sequence diagram.
        """
        # generating sequence diagram for a use-case
        _ = GenerateSequenceDiagram(
            self.driver_path, self.driver_name, self.source_code_path[0])
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(
            self.driver_name, self.driver_path)
        global foo
        foo = self.foo
        foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
        tracer = Trace(countfuncs=1, countcallers=1, timing=1)
        tracer.run('foo.{}()'.format(self.driver_function))

def gruml(source_code_path, **kwargs):
    """driver function of GRUML.
    """
    gruml = GRUML()
    print('Generating RUML for source code at: {}'.format(source_code_path))
    gruml.get_source_code_path_and_modules(source_code_path)
    gruml.get_driver_path_and_driver_name(
        kwargs.get('use_case', None),
        kwargs.get('driver_name', None),
        kwargs.get('driver_path', None),
        kwargs.get('driver_function', None),
    )
    gruml.generate_dependency_data()
    if gruml.use_case:
        gruml.generate_sequential_function_calls()
```

Below is the code for `gruml_cli`:

```
from generate_ruml import gruml
def call_generate_ruml(source_code_link, **kwargs):
    """call gruml function, assume that if use_case is given, all other related 
    arguments will be present, so checking for them can be skipped in here.

    Arguments:
        source_code_link {[type]} -- [description]
    """
    source_code_dir = download_source_code(source_code_link)
    gruml(
        source_code_dir,
        **kwargs
    )

call_generate_ruml(source_code_link, use_case=use_case, driver_name=driver_name, driver_path=driver_path, driver_function=driver_function)
```

This is the error I receive when I call the function from `gruml_cli`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gruml-cli.py", line 64, in <module>
    driver_name=driver_name, driver_path=driver_path, driver_function=driver_function)
  File "gruml-cli.py", line 36, in call_generate_ruml
    **kwargs
  File "/Users/aviralsrivastava/dev/generate_uml/generate_ruml.py", line 249, in gruml
    gruml.generate_sequential_function_calls()
  File "/Users/aviralsrivastava/dev/generate_uml/generate_ruml.py", line 212, in generate_sequential_function_calls
    tracer.run('foo.{}()'.format(self.driver_function))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/trace.py", line 441, in run
    self.runctx(cmd, dict, dict)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/trace.py", line 450, in runctx
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

I also tried to insert the script `generate_ruml.py` in the `sys` path but in vain.

Comment: Treat `foo` as a property of the module and just pass `generate_ruml.foo` around.

Comment: Also, you will need `import generate_ruml` not `from generate_ruml import foo`.

Comment: When does `gruml.foo` get set so that the line `foo = self.foo` doesn't raise an `AttributeError`? (For that matter, what is the purpose of that line, since you immediately overwrite the value of `foo`?)

Comment: See [How do I share global variables across modules?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules) in the Python documentation's [Programming FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#programming-faq).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to import the global variable as well. Like:

```
from generate_ruml import gruml, foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either import the variable as

```
from generate_ruml import gruml, foo
```

Or you can reference the variable as, throughout your code.

```
generate_ruml.foo
```